# RegEx - Excluding characters and minimum count of letters

Tags: html, regex, regex-negation

I wrote a javascript form  validation with a **pattern** in the input tag.

I want exclude these symbols ['<>{}$?!"] everywhere and want a minimum of 3 letters[a-z]{3,}. Everything else should be allowed. (maybe like .*)

My problem is that it only excludes the symbols before the letters and ignores symbols in the middle or the end of the string.

```
<input type="text"
       name="name"
       maxlength=50
       pattern="^[^'<>{}$?!\x22]+[a-z]{3,}.*$"
       onChange="changi(this.parentNode.parentNode.id)"
       required />
```

For example it should be:

True:

- John Doe the 3.
- John Doe

False:

- !!John Doe the 3.
- John Doe !! (atm allowed)
- Jo!hn !! Do!e (atm allowed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead

```
^(?=(?:.*[a-z]){3})[^'<>{}$?!\x22]+$
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/AteRYh/2/)

---

```js
function handle() {
  alert('submitted')
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit='handle()'>
  <input type='text' pattern="^(?=(?:.*[a-z]){3})[^'<>{}$?!\x22]+$"></input>
</form>
```

**Note:-** `\n` inside characters class in regex demo is just for illustration purpose in the case of using in input you don't need that

Comment: Where does the diagram come from?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis this is called regex visualizer, you can check this one  [`jex.im`](https://jex.im/regulex/) which i used to generate the above image